# Return an object as Function in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm looking for more advice than code really. I made an object that contain a deck of cards with methods that shuffles, pluck, and things of that nature. I stored this object in a component and thought that it would be a good idea import this object into the parent component by returning the entire object and importing to treat it like a function. However, it seems that react components only returns JSX. Is there something that I'm missing or is there another way? I do not know. Please help me

Comment: Can you please add a minimally reproducible example as this will make it easier to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just a plain object and also not tied up to your component, then decouple it from your component and put it in a separate module.

And import the module wherever it is needed. But keep in mind, if the object is just a set of functions which takes input and gives you the output then it is okay. But if your want to store the values and reference the same everywhere then you might need to create some different like redux store or a single object

https://codeburst.io/javascript-global-variables-vs-singletons-d825fcab75f9